# consider a sequence $\{X_j\}$ of iid random variables where $X_j$ is in $L_1$ for each j

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a sequence $\{X_j\}_{j\geq1}$ of iid random variables where $X_j$ is in $L_1$ for each $j$.
Suppose that the random variable $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_j-a)$
converges in law to the random variable $W$.

Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j=a$
almost surely.

I know that, by the law of large number, $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ converges almost surely to the expectation of $X_1$. But I don't know how to prove that $a$ is the expectation of $X_1$.

How can I solve it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry! I'm new on this site! Now I edited the question, thank you!

Comment: @saz Hmmm, not true.

Comment: Do we know anything else about the random variable $W$? The tag central-limit-theorem means that $W$ is actually Gaussian random variable, right?

Comment: @Did Am I missing something obvious? See my answer below...

Comment: @saz Your answer below does not reproduce the blunder in your (now deleted) comment. And that is **good**. The blunder in your comment was to state that, for every sequence $(Y_n)$, the convergence in distribution of $Y_n$ would imply the almost sure convergence $Y_n/\sqrt n\to0$.

Comment: @Did Oh, sorry, did I? What I meant to write was "in probability" (and not "almost surely"). Sorry for the confusion....

Comment: Indeed, if $(Y_n)$ converges in distribution then $Y_n/\sqrt n\to0$ in probability. **That** is true.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was looking again at this exercise, but there's a step I don't completely understand. When we say that $\mathbb{P} \biggl(| \frac{S_n}{n} |> \delta \biggr) \leq \mathbb{P} \biggl(|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}| \geq R \biggr)$, this is not true for all deltas, and hence, below, it is not true the convergence in probability (since the limit is $\leq \epsilon$ but not for all $\delta$)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$$S_n := \sum_{j=1}^n (X_j-a).$$

By assumption, $S_n/\sqrt{n} \to W$ in distribution for some real-variabled random variable $W$. Fix $\delta, \epsilon>0$, and choose $R>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|W| \geq R) \leq \epsilon$. Since

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| > \delta \right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \right| \geq R \right)$$

for $n \geq N=N(R)$ sufficently large, we find by the Portmanteau theorem

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| > \delta \right) \leq \mathbb{P}(|W| \geq R) \leq \epsilon.$$

This shows that $S_n/n \to 0$ in probability. As

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \right) - a \right|>\delta \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right|>\delta \right)$$

this means that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \to a$ in probability. On the other hand, we have by the central limit theorem

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j \to \mathbb{E}(X_1)$$

almost surely and hence in probability. Since limits in probability are unique (up to a null set), we get

$$a=\mathbb{E}(X_1).$$

**Remark:** The first part of this proof actually shows the following statement:

> If $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence which converges in distribution, then $\frac{Y_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ in probability.